# Partial specialization of template class copy constructor

Tags: c++, templates, compiler-errors

I'm trying to partially specialize the copy constructor of a very basic templated array class.

```
template<typename D, bool destruct = false> class SimpleArray
{
 SimpleArray(const SimpleArray& other)
 {
  //stuff
 }

 //various other things
}

template<typename D> SimpleArray<D, true>::SimpleArray(const SimpleArray& other)
{
 //different stuff
}
```

But I get this error:

```
'SimpleArray<D,destruct>::{ctor}' : unable to match function definition to an existing declaration
```

However, I've definitely declared the function...  I tried changing the parameter in the partial specialization to `const SimpleArray<D, true>& other` to no avail.  VC++ 11 isn't highlighting the partially specialized function name itself, so I'm guessing the issue is an incorrect name somehow.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot specialize a single member function of a certain partial specialization of a class template: if you want to go the specialization way, you have to specialize the whole class.

However, you could decide to go the overload way instead, and differentiate between the case when `destruct` is `true` and when it is `false` through *tag dispatching*.

For instance, you could define two private member functions called `copy_construct`, as shown below:

```
template<typename D, bool destruct = false>
class SimpleArray
{

    // ...

private:

    void copy_construct(const SimpleArray& other, std::true_type)
    {
        // ...
    }

    void copy_construct(const SimpleArray& other, std::false_type)
    {
        // ...
    }
};
```

And then you could let the copy constructor of your class call the appropriate overload based on the value of the `destruct` parameter:

```
template<typename D, bool destruct = false>
class SimpleArray
{

public:

    // ...

    SimpleArray(const SimpleArray& other)
    {
        copy_construct(other, std::integral_constant<bool, destruct>());
    }

    // ...

};
```

This will invoke the appropriate version of `copy_construct()`, which will do what ought to be done based on the value of the `destruct` parameter.

Answer (score 0):

The compiler message is not helpful (and is no better from G++ or Clang) but it's trying to tell you that you can't define a member function of a partial specialization if you haven't already declared the partial specialization.

i.e. you cannot specialize a single member function of a class template, you have to declare a specialization of the whole class template.  The reason is that the constructor is *not* a template, it's a normal (non-template) member function of a template.  To define a partial specialization you have to specialize the whole class template, you can't specialize a non-template.